# Powershell set-content not working when running script - Possible Compiler Error?

Tags: powershell

I think I'm going crazy but hoping there's an explanation for this weird behavior. I have a script which copies a KIX file to a new location, checks the file version on a new and old version of an EXE, and then modifies the KIX file in multiple places. Below is a simplified version.

The first and the last `set-content` always work. The `set-content` which comes after checking the file versions always fail when I run the whole script (In the whole thing there are multiple instances of `set-content` for different file versions and they all fail).

However, if I put in a breakpoint, or just highlight that section and run it, it does work. I know that section is getting hit because I have further processing in that block not displayed here, like multiple `copy-item`.

When I say fail, I mean that the content does not get updated in the file. There is no error, it just doesn't update.

I've tried putting in `start-sleep` of multiple seconds in between every line and that does not help. I've also tried making it as simple as possible by declaring the version and not running the`fileversioninfo` but it still fails. I'm having a hard time troubleshooting because when I put in a breakpoint, it works.

```
#Declare Paths
$Temp = "\\NewLocation\e$\Temp"
$path = "\\share\folder"
$FinalDest = "\\FinalRestingPlace\Folder"

#Copy file to Temp
Copy-item "\\OtherShare\file1.kix" $Temp 

#Get-Content
$KIXOLD = (get-content $Temp\file1.kix)

#Increment Version Number
[decimal]$OLDVER = 12.0
$NEWVER = ($oldver + .1)
```

This Works

```
#Update Version Number in File 
$VerLine = select-string -Pattern $oldver -path $temp\file1.kix | select -ExpandProperty LineNumber | select -Index 1
$KIXOLD[$VerLine - 1] = "`$ScriptVer = `"$NEWVER`"                                                ; Current Script Version Number"
$KIXOLD | set-content $temp\file1.kix
```

This fails

```
if(Test-Path $path)
{
    if(Test-Path "$path\File1.exe")
    {
    #Check Old And new versions
    $NewVersion = [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo("$path\file1.exe").FileVersion
    $OLDVersion = [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo("$FinalDest\file1.exe").FileVersion

    #Find the old version in the text file and replace with new
    #This FAILS unless there's a breakpoint or it's run separately
    $CONV = $KIXOLD | where {$_ -like "*If `$VAR<`"$OLDVersion*`""}
    ($kixold).Replace("$CONV", "         If `$VAR<`"$NewVersion`"") | set-content $Temp\file1.kix
    }  
}
```

This Works

```
#Update notes to contain current version - THIS WORKS
$linenum = select-string -Pattern $oldver -path $Temp\file1.kix | select -ExpandProperty LineNumber | select -Index 0
$NewLine = [int]$linenum +1
$KIXOLD[$linenum] = ";$NewVer - MyName"
$KIXOLD | set-content $temp\file1.kix
```

Has anyone seen something similar, or have any ideas on why it's failing? I've tested on both a Windows Server 2012 R2 and Windows 10 box with the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question again, and got an answer. For anybody looking:

.Replace method applied to an object does not change that object. Use

```
$CONV = $KIXOLD | where {$_ -like "*If `$VAR<`"1.2.3`""}
$KIXOLD = $kixold.Replace("$CONV", "         If `$VAR<`"1.2.4`"")
$KIXOLD | Set-Content $Temp
```

or

```
$CONV = $KIXOLD | where {$_ -like "*If `$VAR<`"1.2.3`""}
($kixold.Replace("$CONV", "         If `$VAR<`"1.2.4`"")) | Set-Content $Temp
$KIXOLD = (Get-Content $Temp)
```